# ImageView IBOOutlet in a CollectionViewCellClass returns till when trying to initialise it through cellforitemat

Tags: ios, swift

I have a uicollectionview and uses this code to initialise every cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: constants.cellforbadge, for: indexPath) as! BadgeCell
    cell.imageView.image = badges[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Here I set the cells image which the IBOUtlet is in the cell class. Here is the cell class.

```
class BadgeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

}
```

I have added the imgageView in the prototype cell in the collection view in the storyboard, which means that I am not using a xib file.

In the cellforitemat have I tested some solutions but it seems that the the imageView's Iboutlet  of the cell class is equal to nil. It has not been initialised yet.

Why is that? Have I done something wrong?

Thanks you for your time and effort!

Comment: You should check your IBOutlet of imageView

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an XIB as collectionview cell

This is usually happens when you create xib along with cell class . Usual solution is

in the cell xib remove the view and drag and drop a collectionview cell.